# geo:lat,lng uri does not work in phone gap

Tags: android, geo, phonegap

Im quite new to phone gap and mobile app development.
I want to use the geo: uri format to open the google maps application but it does not work.

From what I understand I should be able to just add a line like:

```
<a href="geo:38.897096,-77.036545">test</a>
```

but when I click on the "test" link nothing happens. I created an apk and loaded it onto my device and in the console I get an error 404 not found error for the link geo:38.897096,-77.036545

I found comment that there needs to be an app on the device with the uri associated to the app. the Google Maps app is definitely installed on the device.

I can't find anywhere to set the association for geo: on the phone.

In my config.xml I have an intent line as:

```
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

Questions:

- Is there some setup in the phone gap app for the geo: uri to work ?
- Is there some place on the device to set the association for geo: to 
  google maps
- What am I missing here ? seems so simple. Google    searching
  indicates people have success - but not me.

regards
gmax

Answer (score 0):

Well I did not find a fix for that method but I found a really simple solution to the actual problem - opening google maps app and get turn by turn instructions.

Two lines of code

```
var url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=&daddr=15 south st, tuncurry"
window.open(url, '_system');
```

works like a charm

saddr is the start address (leave it blank for current location)
daddr is the destination address

I hope this helps someone.